# Representing an expression in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

Trying to convert a CNF expression such as

```
(a'+b+c')(a+b+c)
```

to a list in prolog such that it is similar to

```
[[-a,+b,-c],[+a,+b,+c]].
```

Each literal is represented either as positive or negative. i.e. if `a'`this is equivalent to an atom that is `-a`.

Comment: I too am curious how to deal with a' in prolog?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try something like this:

```
cnf(A, F) :-
    atom_chars(A, C),
    conjunction(F, C, []), !.

conjunction([D|C]) --> disjunction(D), conjunction(C).
conjunction([C])   --> disjunction(C).
disjunction(D)     --> ['('], disjuncts(D), [')'].
disjunction(L)     --> literal(L).
disjuncts([L|D])   --> literal(L), disjuncts(D).
disjuncts([L])     --> literal(L).
literal(-P)        --> [+], proposition(P), ['\''].
literal(+P)        --> [+], proposition(P).
literal(-P)        --> proposition(P), ['\''].
literal(+P)        --> proposition(P).
proposition(P)     --> [P], { char_type(P,lower) }.
```

Some examples:

```
?- cnf('a', F).
F = [+a].

?- cnf('a\'', F).
F = [-a].

?- cnf('(a\')(+b)', F).
F = [[-a], [+b]].

?- cnf('(a\'+b+c\')', F).
F = [[-a, +b, -c]].

?- cnf('a\'+b+c\'', F).
F = [-a, +b, -c].

?- cnf('(a\'+b+c\')(a+b+c)', F).
F = [[-a, +b, -c], [+a, +b, +c]].
```

Comment: `conjunction(F, C, [])` ---> `phrase(conjunction(F), C)`. Never ever call directly what you assume is the complied form of a non-terminal.